# Backbone Paginator XML

Tags: jquery, xml, backbone.js

I am trying to use the TVDB Api, but since they are using xml, I am getting these two errors when I use Backbone with the Paginator Plugin:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/xml: "http://thetvdb.com/api/GetSeries.php?seriesname=dexter&callback=jQuery19104464824248570949_1373195205356&_=1373195205357". jquery.js:5
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

My js file looks like this:

```
Tv.Collections.Shows = Backbone.Paginator.requestPager.extend({
    paginator_core: {
        url: Attr.tv.url,
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'text/xml',
    },
    paginator_ui: { currentPage: 0 },
    server_api: {},
    parse: function(resp) {
        c(resp);
    },
});
```

and I am using it like this:

```
Tv.search = new Tv.Collections.Shows;
Tv.search.paginator_core.url = Attr.tv.url + $(ev.target).find('select').val() + '?seriesname=' + $(ev.target).find('.search_input').val();
Tv.search.fetch( function() {
        c(Tv.search);
});
```

Anybody know any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily make use of some awesome services like `Yahoo Pipes`. I have made a pipe for `the tv db`. You can check it here - http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=2e4b059de7a389a0f361ca89b5f9c461&_render=json&seriesname=dexter

What it does is- convert the `XML` to `JSON`.

And, the way you are creating the url is not the `Backbone` way. Don't depend on `DOM` for your data. Don't fetch them directly using `jQuery`. Instead catch the `events`, set data to the model and use them inside.